# What Tea leaves are used in Kashmiri Pink tea

Tags: tea, ingredient-selection

I want to make Kashmiri pink tea but have not found an exact name in English for those tea leaves used in Kashmiri pink tea. As I am right now in china, here they have varieaty of tea. I would like to know the name in English so that i can translate it and find it here

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/whats-the-difference-between-pink-tea-and-other-types-of-tea

Comment: There is no English name for the tea leaves and Olong is different.

Comment: This is what you want? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahwah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kashmiri tea leaves OR pure green tea leaves

克什米爾茶葉或純綠茶葉

克什米尔茶叶或纯绿茶叶

Comment: Erm... some translation or context for the ideographs would be nice.

Comment: It just say the English Version

Comment: 绿茶是 GREEN tea。 克什米尔茶 和 绿茶 是一样吗？